# Here Maps SDK insert string to play Audio

Tags: navigation, here-api, here-maps-rest

Can i know the Here_maps Android SDK api to play voice , I need it because if i play using TTS engine then both are having different accent(Robotic voice in TTS and natural voice in here maps guidance)

I tried using "com.google.android.tts" engine but it's having again robotic voice output.

Comment: Can you please describe clearly what you want to do. Thank you.

Comment: I need Here maps api to pass string so that i will give voice output. Actually i am having usecase of  play a string after there is an voice guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Our Mobile SDK comes with voice skins that support both Text-to-Speech (TTS) and natural voice audio files for navigation. You can select a voiceskin to be used during navigation but you cannot control what is said. If you are playing voice using TTS in you app, then you can select a TTS voice skin to be used for navigation to make all sound consistent.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-voice-instructions.html

Currently, we do not provide an interface to play custom audio via string inputs.